# Change proxy_cache_key to use header token as part of its key

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to configure nginx proxy_cache_key to include a specific header as a key instead of just request/args?

I would like to cache my API GET hits and am using x-authtoken in my headers for authentication. This is ignored currently, so another user will get the cache of a previous user if I leave cache enabled.

Comment: It's possible. All headers are mapped to variables named`$http_...` http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_

Comment: @AlexeyTen you saved me !!! :-)

Answer (score 12):

@Alexy Ten posted the link to the correct location in the docs, but just to make it easier for people in the future:

> $http_name arbitrary request header field; the last part of a variable
> name is the field name converted to lower case with dashes replaced by
> underscores

So in your case it would look like: `proxy_cache_key $http_x_authtoken`.

Comment: Thanks for this, just be sure to convert dashes to underscores as the docs say. I was able to cache AJAX requests using the `$http_x_requested_with` header. My full cache key looks like this: `fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$http_x_requested_with;`

Comment: Thanks @PhilippClaßen!